# Como puedo conectar la base de datos en python con flask

Tags: python, mysql, flask

tengo una duda, estoy siguiente el codigo de un video tutorial donde ya instale los paquetes solicitados para trabajar con las base de datos en python y el codigo hasta el momento lo tengo asi:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL



app = Flask(__name__)


mysql = MySQL()
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST']='localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER']='root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD']=''
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB']='sistema'
mysql.init_app(app)


@app.route('/')
def index():

    sql="INSERT INTO `empleados` (`id`, `nombre`, `correo`, `foto`) VALUES (NULL, 'Miguel', 'miguelberrio@gmail.com', 'foto_perfil.jpg');"
    conn= mysql.connect()
    cursor=conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    conn.commit()


    return render_template('empleados/index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

pero al momento de ejecutar en un navegador para ingresar al servicor y mostrar en la pagina lo que escribi en el archivo html me sale error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\migue\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flaskext\mysql.py", line 5, in 
from flask import _app_ctx_stack as _ctx_stack
ImportError: cannot import name '*app_ctx_stack' from 'flask' (C:\Users\migue\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flask_*init**.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\PythonProjects\Main_project\app.py", line 4, in 
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
File "C:\Users\migue\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flaskext\mysql.py", line 7, in 
from flask import _request_ctx_stack as _ctx_stack
ImportError: cannot import name '*request_ctx_stack' from 'flask' (C:\Users\migue\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flask_*init**.py)

entonces no se como puedo acomodarlo, alguno me podria indicar cual es el error, sabiendo que lo estoy haciendo de acuerdo a lo indicado en el video tutorial. La version que tengo de flask es la 3.0.1

Comment: Al parecer, en tu caso es importante mencionar qué versión de Flask estás utilizando. Pulsa en [edit] para agregar esa información, y por cierto, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Por último: elimina [php], ya que nada tiene que ver con la pregunta, y [localhost], que es una _meta-etiqueta_.

Comment: y esto que tiene que ver con php y localhost?